# How to login to a website with Jsoup for web scraping

Tags: java, web-scraping, jsoup

I am having trouble to login to website using jsoup.

I have tried almost every thing. Read different blog/tutorials but none have helped. Here is the code that i have written so far

```java
Connection.Response res = Jsoup.connect(url)
                               .method(Method.GET)
                               .execute();

Connection.Response login = Jsoup.connect(url) 
        .data("username", uname, "password", pass, "anchor", "")
        .cookies(res.cookies())
        .method(Method.GET)
        .execute();

Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url)
      .cookies(login.cookies())
      .get();
       String title = doc.title();

                System.out.println("title is: " + title);
```

Comment: You should probably use a POST request to submit the form data.

Comment: @t.m.adam thanks for help i have tried it but no use

Comment: I can't really help without the URL but try the following: make sure that you have the correct login URL (the form's action), make sure to post all form fieelds (CSRF token, other hidden fields), maybe User-Agent or other headers are required, maybe JavaScript is involved.

Answer (score 0):

I have a problem with login process with Jsoup, I found the login has two pages, first (GET): https://www.dgr.gub.uy/sr/loginStart.jsf second (Post): https://www.dgr.gub.uy/sr/j_security_check

```
public Document getDocumentSix(String defaultUrl, String host) {
        Connection.Response response = null;
        Document document = null;
    try {
        Connection connection = Jsoup.connect(defaultUrl)
                .headers(this.getRequestHeaderBefore(host))
                .method(Connection.Method.GET);
        response = connection.execute();

    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        Connection.Response responseTwo = null;
        Map<String, String> cookies = response.cookies();

        responseTwo = Jsoup.connect("https://www.dgr.gub.uy/sr/j_security_check")
                .headers(this.getRequestHeaderAfter(cookies.get("JSESSIONID")))
                .data("j_username", "6551990")
                .data("j_password", "VNZANU")
                .cookies(cookies)
                .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.157 Safari/537.36")
                .method(Connection.Method.POST)
                .execute();

        document = responseTwo.parse();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return document;
}
```